# how to fix this Separator unmatched and wordlist.txt: No such file or directory?

Tags: hashcat

```
MacBook:~ apple$ `hashcat -m 22000 capture.hccapx wordlist.txt`
hashcat (v6.2.5) starting

wordlist.txt: No such file or directory

Started: Thu *** ** 14:36:23 ****
Stopped: Thu ** ** 14:36:23 ****

MacBook:~ apple$ `hashcat -m 22000 -a3 capture.hccapx "?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d`
hashcat (v6.2.5) starting

* Device #2: This device's local mem size is too small.

OpenCL API (OpenCL 1.2 (May  7 2020 00:10:14)) - Platform #1 [Apple]
====================================================================
* Device #1: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz, 2016/4096 MB (512 MB allocatable), 2MCU
* Device #2: GeForce 320M, skipped

Minimum password length supported by kernel: 8
Maximum password length supported by kernel: 63

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 1 (HCPX): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 2 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 3 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 4 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 5 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 6 (????l?"?:9M†N??~Ry): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 7 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 8 (????l?"?:9M†N??~R): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 9 (????l?"?:9M†N??~Ry): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 10 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 11 (????l?"?:9M†N??~R): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 12 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 13 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 14 (??my): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 15 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 16 (??m): Separator unmatched

Hashfile 'capture.hccapx' on line 17 (??my): Separator unmatched

Hashfile capture.hccapx on line 18 (): Separator unmatched

Hashfile capture.hccapx on line 19 (??m): Separator unmatched

No hashes loaded.

Started: Thu *** ** 14:36:39 ****
Stopped: Thu *** ** 14:36:40 ****
```

how to fix this Separator unmatched and wordlist.txt: No such file or directory?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, Hashcat has deprecated the original method "-m 2500" to crack wpa2 and suggested "-m 22000".
I've founded an solution by googling a little bit and in this Q&A https://github.com/risinek/esp32-wifi-penetration-tool/issues/14
they suggest to use "-m 2500" and add "--deprecated-check-disable" to work with.